# Is it possible to set watermark in the Google Dataflow to current system time?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is it possible to set watermark in the Google Dataflow to current system time?

Is it possible to set watermark in the Google Dataflow to current system time? Im using Sliding Window 10 seconds every 5 seconds, but wery offten multiple sliding windows firing at the same time (some ot them has delay 20-30 seconds some 0).
[3 windows fires at the same time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lR30.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.